# How to use WhenAnyValue with more properties

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

The `WhenAnyValue` method is overloaded for up to 12 properties.

What is the recommended way of handling an arbitrarily large number of properties, more than can be handled by the defined overloads of `WhenAnyValue`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really must handle that many properties at once (omg, why?), I would suggest breaking up the properties into multiple calls to `WhenAnyValue` and combining them with `CombineLatest`. Since you're combining them all with `WhenAnyValue` anyway, I imagine this should work fine.

Example:

```
var group1 = this.WhenAnyValue(@this => @this.Prop1, ..., (prop1, ...) => ...);
var group2 = this.WhenAnyValue(@this => @this.Prop13, ..., (prop13, ...) => ...);
group1.CombineLatest(group2, (g1, g2) => ...);
```

`WhenAnyValue` just uses `CombineLatest` [under the hood](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/src/ReactiveUI/VariadicTemplates.tt#L103) anyway.

Alternatively, you could create additional overloads to support more values. There isn't really a limit on the number of type parameters.

Comment: Wouldn't `.Merge` be a better choice than `.CombineLatest`?

Comment: Technically wouldn't matter in this case since WhenAnyValue() will fire a default(T) to start with but Merge would be cleaner to what is being intended.

Comment: @Enigmativity How would you combine the property values with Merge? I don't follow.

Comment: @GlennWatson [I'm not seeing an overload for `Merge`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/IQueryLanguage.cs#L519) with the result selector like is shown in your edit. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan - `group1.Merge(group2)`. Of course you'd need to flatten out the tuples.

Comment: `WhenAnyValue` even uses `CombineLatest` [under the hood](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/src/ReactiveUI/VariadicTemplates.tt#L103), so I still don't see the point in trying to use `Merge` when you'd have to perform extra steps `CombineLatest` already does.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan - Because `.CombineLatest` only produces a value when both of the source observables produce a value. You're effectively missing the first value that's produced until the second value comes along. With `.Merge` you get the first value immediately.

Comment: @TaylorBuchanan, accepting your answer as it put me on the right track. I hear your cry of "OMG, why?", and it was my original reaction when the customer showed me the UI they want. I tried to get them to split the monster, but they're holding on to it. Thanks.